# How to work with the api using axios vue.js

Tags: arrays, api, vue.js, axios, get-request

I have a list of radiobutton car brands, how do I get an array of models from the server after selecting a certain brand and display it on a new page? What specific actions are needed for this? Thank you so much for reading this

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Brands',
  data() {
    return {
      brands: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    next: function () {
      this.$router.push({path: '/model'})
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.axios
        .get('https:***')
        .then(response => (this.brands = response.data.brands))
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
  },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="alphabet-wrap">
    <ul class="alphabet">
      <li v-for="brand in brands"
          :key="brand.name"
          :class="brand.id"
      >
        <label :for="brand.id"
               @change="next"
        >
          <input type="radio"
                 :id="brand.id"
                 name="brand"
          >
          <span class="text">{{ brand.name }}</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: depends strongly on what your backend/api looks like. But in general I'd say: Select brand -> redirect to new site using brand as query param and then requesting all models of brand via get request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use **v-model** to store selected brand in data

```html
<input type="radio"
  :id="brand.id"
  name="brand"
  v-model="selectedBrand"
>
```

Now you should pass **brand** name in query params as below:

```js
this.$router.push({
 path: '/models',
 query: {
   brand: this.selectedBrand
 }
})

// Route will be like https://example.com/models?brand=brand-name
```

In component who render `/models` page, call api request with **brand-name**

```js
<template>
  <div v-if="brandModels.length">
    {{ brandModels }}
  </div>

  <div v-else>Loading...</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      brandModels: []
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const url = `https:***/models?brand=${this.$route.query.brand}`;
      const response = await this.axios.get(url);
      this.brandModels = response.data
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
`selectedBrand` is stored in components data

```js
//...
data() {
   return {
     selectedBrand: ""
   };
}
//...
```

Comment: And where and how do I store the selected brand? and all subsequent forms

Comment: You should define `selectedBrand` in component(who render the form) data, check update